# Cheap Wifi Router with built-in 4G modem and openvpn support

Tags: wifi, networking, router, 4g

I'm looking for a router with the following specifications:

- Wireless N
- OpenVPN client support (to connect to an openvpn access server)
- Built in 3G/4G Modem with SIM slot (3G: 850MHz/2100MHz, 4G: 700MHz/1800Mhz)

I have found Industrial M2M Routers such as the Netcomm NTC-140W matching my needs however I don't wish to spend as much as $800.

Comment: Do you have a budget for this?

Comment: I think a used smartphone will be your best bet. Do you have the chops to reconfigure it with a new ROM and wifi tether?

Comment: Cfinley - somewhere between $100-$200

Comment: Dan Whaley- I would do what but I'm after quite a few of then, also need a more reliable setup